# java.lang.NullPointerException,at ✽.Given product is set with the following fields(src/test/resources/features/wizard/wizardNewProduct.feature:

Tags: java, cucumber, api, rest-assured, api-automation

Pls, I need help, I'm getting a null pointer exception, When I send a request, I'm catching values in Cucumber through the `List<Map<String, String>>`.

I'm testing API with Rest Assured and Cucumber, and I have the following POGO classes:

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.List;

 @Data

 public class ProductRequest {

    private String address;

    private double latitude;

    private boolean active;

    private List<ProductTypes> productTypes;

    private List<ProductVideos> productVideos;

    private String shortDescription;

    private String fullDescription;

    private boolean mostPopular;

    private String calendarColor;

    private String name;

    private List<ProductWorkingDates> productWorkingDates;

    private double longitude;

}

 import lombok.Data;

@Data

public class ProductTypes {

    private String name;
    private String id;
}

 import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;
@Data

public class ProductWorkingDates {
    private String fromDate;
    private String toDate;
    private String name;
    private Boolean strictHours;
    private List<TimeSlots> timeSlots;
    private String deletedAt;
    private Integer maxUsedTicketsQuantity;
    private  Integer errorCode;
}

import lombok.Data;

@Data

public class TimeSlots {
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private String duration;
    private String quantity;
    private Integer usedQuantity;
    private boolean active;
    private String deletedAt;
    private String dayOfWeek;
}
```

And I have my Cucumber Scenarios

```
Feature: Creating a new product
 
  Scenario: provider creates a new product
    Given product is set with the following fields
      | name             | active | shortDescription      | fullDescription               | mostPopular | longitude | latitude     | calendarColor | address |
      | AutoTestPositive | true   | Test For Automation 1 | Automation for API in Postman | true        | 456.456   | 3245678.5467 | blue          | Bishkek |

  Scenario: provider enters a data in productTypes
    Given product types is set with following fields
      | name    | id       |
      | TestAPI | 5bpJ0olV |

  Scenario: provider enters a data in ProductWorkingDates
    Given product Working Dates is set with following fields
      | fromDate        | toDate          | name                | strictHours | deletedAt | maxUsedTicketsQuantity | errorCode |
      | Thu May 27 2021 | Sat Dec 31 2022 | 1234567sdfgh#$#%^%& | false       |           | 0                      | 0         |

  Scenario: provider enters a data in time Slots
    Given product time Slots is set with the following fields
      | active | endTime  | dayOfWeek | duration | quantity | startTime | usedQuantity |
      | false  | 20:00:00 | Monday    | 01:00    | 67       | 09:00:00  | 0            |

 
  Scenario: Provider creates a new product
    Given provider creates a new product
```

And I have My StepDefenition class

```
public class CreateNewProductSteps {

    private Response response;
    public ProductRequest productRequest ;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = PropertiesReader.getPropertiesValue("Book_It_BaseURL");

    }

    @Given("^provider creates a new product$")
    public void providerCreatesANewProduct() {

        String newProd = ObjectConverter.convertObjectToJson(productRequest);
        RestHttpRequest.addHeaders();

        response = RestHttpRequest
                .requestSpecification
                .body(newProd)
                .when()
                .request(String.valueOf(RestHttpRequest.HttpMethods.POST), "/api/product");
    }

    @Given("^product is set with the following fields$")
    public void productIsSetWithTheFollowingFields(List<Map<String, String>> product) {

        productRequest.setName(product.get(0).get("name"));
        productRequest.setActive(Boolean.parseBoolean(product.get(0).get("active")));
        productRequest.setShortDescription(product.get(0).get("shortDescription"));
        productRequest.setFullDescription(product.get(0).get("fullDescription"));
        productRequest.setMostPopular(Boolean.parseBoolean(product.get(0).get("mostPopular")));
        productRequest.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(product.get(0).get("longitude")));
        productRequest.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(product.get(0).get("latitude")));
        productRequest.setCalendarColor(product.get(0).get("calendarColor"));
        productRequest.setAddress(product.get(0).get("address"));

    }

    @Given("^product types is set with following fields$")
    public void productTypesIsSetWithFollowingFields(List<Map<String, String>> productTypes) {

        ProductTypes productTypes1 = new ProductTypes();
        productTypes1.setId(productTypes.get(0).get("id"));
        productTypes1.setName(productTypes.get(0).get("name"));

        List<ProductTypes> productTypesList = new ArrayList<>();
        productTypesList.add(productTypes1);
        productRequest.setProductTypes(productTypesList);
    }

    @Given("^product Working Dates is set with following fields$")
    public void productWorkingDatesIsSetWithFollowingFields(List<Map<String, String>> productWorkingDates) {

        ProductWorkingDates productWorkingDates1 = new ProductWorkingDates();
        productWorkingDates1.setFromDate(productWorkingDates.get(0).get("fromDate"));
        productWorkingDates1.setToDate(productWorkingDates.get(0).get("toDate"));
        productWorkingDates1.setName(productWorkingDates.get(0).get("name"));
        productWorkingDates1.setStrictHours(Boolean.parseBoolean(productWorkingDates.get(0).get("strictHours")));
        productWorkingDates1.setDeletedAt(productWorkingDates.get(0).get("deletedAt"));
        productWorkingDates1.setMaxUsedTicketsQuantity(Integer.parseInt(productWorkingDates.get(0).get("maxUsedTicketsQuantity")));
        productWorkingDates1.setErrorCode(Integer.parseInt(productWorkingDates.get(0).get("errorCode")));

        List<ProductWorkingDates> listProductWorkingDates = new ArrayList<>();
        listProductWorkingDates.add(productWorkingDates1);
        productRequest.setProductWorkingDates(listProductWorkingDates);
    }

    @Given("^product time Slots is set with the following fields$")
    public void productTimeSlotsIsSetWithTheFollowingFields(List<Map<String, String>> timeSlots) {

        ProductWorkingDates productWorkingDates1 = new ProductWorkingDates();

        TimeSlots timeSlots1 = new TimeSlots();
        timeSlots1.setActive(Boolean.parseBoolean(timeSlots.get(0).get("active")));
        timeSlots1.setEndTime(timeSlots.get(0).get("endTime"));
        timeSlots1.setDayOfWeek(timeSlots.get(0).get("dayOfWeek"));
        timeSlots1.setDuration(timeSlots.get(0).get("duration"));
        timeSlots1.setQuantity(timeSlots.get(0).get("quantity"));
        timeSlots1.setStartTime(timeSlots.get(0).get("startTime"));
        timeSlots1.setUsedQuantity(Integer.parseInt(timeSlots.get(0).get("usedQuantity")));

        List<TimeSlots> timeSlotsList = new ArrayList<>();
        timeSlotsList.add(timeSlots1);
        productWorkingDates1.setTimeSlots(timeSlotsList);

        List<ProductWorkingDates> listProductWorkingDates = new ArrayList<>();
        listProductWorkingDates.add(productWorkingDates1);

        productRequest.setProductWorkingDates(listProductWorkingDates);

    }
```

This is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at www.logisense.com.cucumber.steps.newProduct.CreateNewProductSteps.productIsSetWithTheFollowingFields(CreateNewProductSteps.java:54)
    at ✽.Given product is set with the following fields(src/test/resources/features/wizard/wizardNewProduct.feature:7)


  Scenario: provider creates a new product         # src/test/resources/features/wizard/wizardNewProduct.feature:6
    Given product is set with the following fields # CreateNewProductSteps.productIsSetWithTheFollowingFields(String,String>>)
      java.lang.NullPointerException
        at www.logisense.com.cucumber.steps.newProduct.CreateNewProductSteps.productIsSetWithTheFollowingFields(CreateNewProductSteps.java:54)
        at ✽.Given product is set with the following fields(src/test/resources/features/wizard/wizardNewProduct.feature:7)
      

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at www.logisense.com.cucumber.steps.newProduct.CreateNewProductSteps.productTypesIsSetWithFollowingFields(CreateNewProductSteps.java:80)
    at ✽.Given product types is set with following fields(src/test/resources/features/wizard/wizardNewProduct.feature:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing your `productRequest`. So lines like:

```java
productRequest.setName(...);
```

or

```java
productRequest.setProductTypes(...);
```

obviously fail.